# Django to show status of running os command

Tags: python, django, operating-system, subprocess

I am using django to create an app which will take the targets from the text file and then will launch the Nmap scan against the hosts specified.

Everything is working fine with the only problem being showing status of the running command on browser's screen.Since I am running the command with `os.system(command)`, I can get the output at terminal from where I have launched the runserver command.

But, I am just wondering if there is any way to redirect the output to the web browsers screen.

Comment: is there anybody to answer this